# Android CursorAdapter getView / newView should be inflate same things?

Tags: android

I read many post in SOF about CursorAdaptor - newView / getView / bindView.

If i create a custom adaptor for AutoComplete Text Field, i have to implement newView() and bindView().

But someone say, implement getView() can improve the speed when scrolling.

So the question is,

if on newView(), already inflate a view.

```
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    // =Single Line=
    final TextView view = (TextView) inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
    String item = createItem(cursor);
    view.setText(item);    
    return view;
}
```

So on getView(), i do same things on it?

Comment: who is "someone"? source?

Comment: `view.setText(item);` should be in bindView, not newView (also, look at the code. getView in CursorAdapter calls newView (if needed) and bindView after.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implementing `getView()` or the `newView()/bindView()` group is the same thing in terms of performance and you should choose the later option. For `Cursor` based adapters the `getView()` method is implemented so it uses the view recycling mechanism along with delegating the row construction to the `newView()`(build the views of the row) and `bindView()`(bind the data to the rows) methods. It also moves the `Cursor` to the correct position.

Also, as njzk2 , pointed out you should set the data on the view in the `bindView()` method. The `newView()` method will not be called for every row of the `ListView`, it will be called only for the case when there isn't a recycled row already available, that's why you should **only** build the row view in `newView()`. The `bindView()` method, however, will be called each time and here's where you should bind the data from the `Cursor` to the row views.

Comment: If it recycles rows, does that mean we don't need to implement the ViewHolder pattern?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Cursor based adapters have implemented the recycling mechanism but they didn't implement the holder pattern to avoid looking for views directly when doing the data binding. If you want a little more performance for your `ListView` then you should implement the holder patter yourself in the `newView()` method.